# When I save a document, can I enter the location with path input?

Tags: folders

When I save a document in any editing program, it pops up a save window where I can choose the desired save location by clicking folder names.

Instead of mouse-clicks, I like to input the path name directly using keyboards. For example,

1. when I want to save a document in the folder of `\Users\myusername\Dropbox\myfoldername`, I want to actually type it.
2. In the current working directory, I want to create a sub-directory and save it. In such a case, I want to actually type something like `subfoldername\filename.ext`, instead of create a new folder and then save.

Is it possible?

Comment: Note that slashes for paths on OS X are /Users/myusername/...  Do want it that way or the more windows like way you have noted in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, just start typing the path you want to use in the Save As: field. The Go to Folder dialog will appear when you type / or ~ and let you type your path. Type your path and press return. You can include the filename at the end of the path and it will update the name automatically.
You can also access the Go to Folder dialog manually using  <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>⇧</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>.

You can't create a new folder by typing the path, but you can use a keyboard shortcut to create the folder. Use Go to Folder to get as deep as you can into existing folders, then type 
<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>⇧</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd>. Type the name of the folder and press enter.

The field with the filename will selected, so you can just type your name and press return.

---

This question has inspired a [post on the Ask Different Blog](http://apple.blogoverflow.com/2012/03/open-and-save-like-a-pro-secrets-of-opensave-dialogs/) that contains the answer, as well as other tips for working with open/save dialogs.

Comment: That's better ;)